# Create a table from the count and percentage of different columns in a DF

Tags: r, data-wrangling

I got this df

```
    structure(list(patients = 1:10, adm1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 
1, 1, 1), adm2 = c(0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1), adm3 = c(0, 
0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1), adm4 = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 
1, 0)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I want a table like this

```
               adm1  adm2  adm3 adm4
No of patients  10    5     3    2
Percentage      100%   50%  30%  20%
```

[image: 1]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `colSums` and `colMeans` -

```
rbind(no_of_patients = colSums(df[-1]), 
      percentage = colMeans(df[-1]) * 100)

#.              adm1 adm2 adm3 adm4
#no_of_patients   10    5    4    2
#percentage      100   50   40   20
```

Answer (score 2):

Try `colSums` and `colMeans`

```
t(
  sapply(
    c(no_of_patients = colSums, percentage = colMeans),
    function(f) f(df[-1])
  )
)
```

which gives

```
               adm1 adm2 adm3 adm4
no_of_patients   10  5.0  4.0  2.0
percentage        1  0.5  0.4  0.2
```